# Gorm nested query contains Any

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class

```
Post {
hasMany [comments : Comment]
}

Comment {
 belongsTo [post: Post]
 User user
}
```

I would like to search all the posts that contain any comment from a specific User.

Something like

```
        def posts = Post.findAll
        {(
            //condition1 ||
            // condition 2 ||
            comments.containsAny(Comment.findByUser(User.get(params.userId)))
//if the post contains any comment from this user, get it
        )}
```

Any idea how i can do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This criteria query should do it

```
def user = User.get(params.userId)

def posts = Post.createCriteria().listDistinct {

  comments {
    eq 'user', user
  }
}
```

`listDistinct` ensures that if a user comments on a post several times, the post is only retrieved once.